Let $G\leq E(2)$ be discrete and $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ so that Sym(F)={id}. When is G = Sym{g.x | $g\in G, x\in F$}?
Let $G\leq E(2)$ be discrete and $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ so that Sym(F)={id}. When is G = Sym{g.x | $g\in G, x\in F$}.
I have problems with following task:
b) Show that in general G $\neq$ Sym{g.x | $g\in G, x\in F$}
c) Find F, so that G = Sym{g.x | $g\in G, x\in F$}

The notation $E(2)$ is not immediately clear, but from the context, I guess you refer to the group of Euclidean isometries of the plane.

Yes, thats what I meant.

Let
$$
G_n=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi/n)&-\sin(2\pi/n)\\\sin(2\pi/n)&\cos(2\pi/n)\end{bmatrix}: k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\right\}\cong\mathbb Z_n.
$$
Now we consider $F=\{(0,0),(1,0),(\cos(2\pi/n),\sin(2\pi/n)),(2,0)\}$. Clearly,
$$
G_nF=\{(0,0),(\cos(2\pi/n),\sin(2\pi/n)),2(\cos(2\pi/n),\sin(2\pi/n)) :k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\}
$$ so that $\mathrm{Iso}(G_nF)\cong\mathrm{D}_{2n}$.
Now, if $n\geq3$, then $\mathrm{Iso}(F)=\mathrm{Id}$.
This answers (b).
If
$$
D_{2n}=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi/n)&-\sin(2\pi/n)\\\sin(2\pi/n)&\cos(2\pi/n)\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi/n)&\sin(2\pi/n)\\\sin(2\pi/n)&-\cos(2\pi/n)\end{bmatrix}: k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\right\}\cong\mathrm{D}_{2n},
$$ then $D_{2n}F=G_nF$, so that $\mathrm{Iso}(D_{2n}F)=D_{2n}\cong\mathrm{D}_{2n}$. And this soles (c).
Another solution for (c), can be obtained by taking $F=\{(0,0),(1,0),(1,1/n)\}$, then you can see that $\mathrm{Iso}(G_n F)=G_n$ and $\mathrm{Iso}(F)=\mathrm{Id}$.

I´d like to ask, what do I do, if I don´t know G exactly.

If $G$ is a finite group and $F$ is bounded, then $GF$ will also be bounded, thus $\mathrm{Iso}(GF)$ will be a finite group and thus will be either a cyclic group or a dihedral group. In general $G\leq\mathrm{Iso}(GF)$. And for any finite $G$ you can find some $F$ (asymmetric if you want) so that $\mathrm{Iso}(GF)$ is any supergroup of $G$. The case in which $G$ is infinite will probably work as well.

Thank you Daniele
